# Mahout 0.9 classify document for Naive Bayes

Tags: java, machine-learning, mahout

I'm very new to Mahout and I am working on classifying unstructured text documents.

I have followed [this tutorial](http://chimpler.wordpress.com/2013/03/13/using-the-mahout-naive-bayes-classifier-to-automatically-classify-twitter-messages/) as I am using a Naive Bayes Model. I have gotten to the point of training my classifier but I am not sure how to convert a new document into a tfidf vector for classifying.

My data is stored as a TSV file which has a label and the text corresponding to it. I use `seq2parse` to create the tfidf vectors that is required for training the model.

I then train the model using these tfidf vectors which results in a Naive Bayes model.

Now I have a new unlabelled text document that I wish to classify using this trained model but I am not sure how to convert it into a tfidf vector. If I use `seq2parse` again then it will create a new set of dictionary file etc and I assume then this doesn't correspond to the dictionary created for the training set.

I have seen a manual implementation of creating the tfidf based on an already created dictionary file and label index at https://github.com/fredang/mahout-naive-bayes-example/blob/master/src/main/java/com/chimpler/example/bayes/Classifier.java but I was wondering if Mahout has already provided some methods to do this just the way they have provided the `seq2parse`. I would rather use a supporting method of doing it than having to do it manually.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you correctly, but why don't you create the term frequency matrix using the training as well as the test documents and then merge the training vectors with their labels?

Comment: @visakh It is not for testing. Let's say I have a new unclassified document and I want to label it... how would I create the tfidf vector for it?

Comment: I meant I want to label it using the classifier model

Comment: I guess you would have to create the document term matrix based on the entire dataset, including the classified ones (which you are using for training) and the unclassified ones. Otherwise, the dimensions of the term matrix won't be appropriate since the words in the classified and unclassified documents could be different.

Comment: Exactly! So I was wondering if mahout provides a way to pass in the dictionary file generated to base the tfidf on. Otherwise I will have to follow the chimpler example and do it manually.

Comment: @nbz: I'm facing the same problem as yours, did you find any solution for this problem?

Comment: @H.Z. This was quite some time back so I am not exactly sure, but I remember adapting the code and building my own method to get the tfidf using that github link in my answer. That was the only way. I didn't find any way to do it through mahout.

Answer (score 0):

The sample code can help u, perhaps:

```
org.apache.mahout.math.Vector vector = new RandomAccessSparseVector();
    Integer wordId = dictionary.get(word);  // use hashcode of word

    double tfIdfValue = tfidf.calculate(count, freq.intValue(),
            wordCount, documentCount); // calculate tf*idf

    vector.set(wordId,tfIdfValue);

// Model is a matrix (wordId, labelId) => probability score
NaiveBayesModel model = NaiveBayesModel.materialize(
        new Path(modelPath), configuration);
StandardNaiveBayesClassifier classifier = new StandardNaiveBayesClassifier(
        model);

// With the classifier, we get one score for each label.The label with
// the highest score is the one the tweet is more likely to be
// associated to
Vector resultVector = classifier.classifyFull(vector);
```